# Take data between a comma from a SQL row PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli

I'm about to write this code which stores numbers in a database, for example it's 1,2,3,4. I know how to store it in the database, etc, but I need to know to get those numbers out of the database, everyone on it's own where it can be used as a variable.

Example:
Database has a column called IDs, IDs contains the following:
1,2,3,4,5
In PHP I want to take every number in the column IDs, so there's a variable for every number.
$variable = 1;
$variable = 2;
etc

Comment: You shouldn't store data like this in your database, since it's not going to be normalized this way. You should follow [this link](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm) and try to plan the whole thing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can parse the string into an array of variables with one element of the array per number.

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5';
$arr = explode(',', $str);

echo $arr[0]; // 1
echo $arr[1]; // 2
echo $arr[2]; // 3
echo $arr[3]; // 4
echo $arr[4]; // 5
```

However, storing strings of IDs in a database is generally undesirable. Usually there is a better database structure that can be used.

For example by using an additional table to associate rows from two other tables:

```
customers ( id, name, date_of_birth )

customer_addresses ( id, line1, line2, town, city )

customer_address_assoc ( customer_id, customer_address_id )
```

Using the explode method, you may have stored a field on the customer table such as `address_ids`. But by using an association table, this is a much better structure. It's easier to query, faster and generally more optimized. The association table would store a row for every address associated to the customer.

Comment: Thanks very much, can you explain to me the better database structure that can be used?

Comment: but it might have like hundreds of rows. will take a lot of work.

Comment: hundreds of rows is no problem because you're only storing IDs. MySQL can handle millions of rows in this way.

Comment: Storing an int requires way less memory than storing a varchar. As I said on my previous comment, you should normalize your database. [Check this out](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm)

Comment: looks interesting, will look into it, thanks everyone. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to to this is using a foreach cycle but it depends on what you need.

This examples echoes all your numbers:

```
<?php 

                            foreach($querynumberas $number){                                
                            $id = $number['id'];
echo $id;
}

?>
```

But this doesn't store all variables as you need, so to do this you should use this construct:

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1; $i <= array.lenght(); ++$i) {
   ${'number'.$i} = $number['number'.$i]; // it stores: number1 = 1; number2 = 7; ecc

    }

php?>
```

Comment: wouldnt that make the server lag like hell? i was thinking about a function that has data variables for example explode like mrcode told me. thanks for this new idea though.

Comment: Lag for a for cycle? nah, i don't think. Lag is usually due to multiple sql queries but you have one in his code and one in mine. You asked for variables width different name, MrCode gave an array with numbers stored in position, i just answered for what you asked. :-)

Comment: i didn't want variables with different names, just didn't know how to explain it very well. thanks anyways.